# Compile errors (C4430 C2143 etc.) in VS2010 on Windows XP, not Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, mfc, visual-studio-2005, windows-xp

I am trying to convert my MFC project created with VS2005 to VS2010. When I try to compile the project on my laptop (Windows 7 x64), it runs without any problems with VS2010, but the other computer (strangely where the project was created) gives a bunch of errors all in winuser.h (below). I tried to research and trace the cause to no avail, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Error   4   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winuser.h 11405   1   Visualization
Error   5   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winuser.h   11408 1   Visualization
Error   7   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winuser.h 11412   1   Visualization
Error   8   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winuser.h 11415   1   Visualization
Error   10  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winuser.h 11419   1   Visualization
Error   11  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winuser.h 11422   1   Visualization
Error   24  error C2513: 'BOOL *' : no variable declared before '=' c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winuser.h 11492   1   Visualization
Error   18  error C2491: 'GetMonitorInfoW' : definition of dllimport data not allowed   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winuser.h 11484   1   Visualization
Error   14  error C2491: 'GetMonitorInfoA' : definition of dllimport data not allowed   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winuser.h 11478   1   Visualization
Error   21  error C2275: 'LPRECT' : illegal use of this type as an expression   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winuser.h 11492   1   Visualization
Error   22  error C2275: 'LPARAM' : illegal use of this type as an expression   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winuser.h 11492   1   Visualization
Error   20  error C2275: 'HDC' : illegal use of this type as an expression  c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winuser.h 11492   1   Visualization
Error   23  error C2165: 'left-side modifier' : cannot modify pointers to data  c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winuser.h 11492   1   Visualization
Error   12  error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'hMonitor'    c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winuser.h 11478   1   Visualization
Error   16  error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'hMonitor'    c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winuser.h 11484   1   Visualization
Error   3   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__stdcall'  c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winuser.h 11405   1   Visualization
Error   6   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__stdcall'  c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winuser.h 11412   1   Visualization
Error   9   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__stdcall'  c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winuser.h 11419   1   Visualization
Error   15  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winuser.h 11479   1   Visualization
Error   19  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winuser.h 11485   1   Visualization
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a problem between different machines or between different build configs (win32 vs x64)? If it is the former, diff the winuser.h files on both machines, they should be identical.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

Sebastiaan